# How can I setup PGFPlots to work with gnuplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, texworks, shell-escape

**Notes:** I'm using Windows 8 and TeXworks. Also, I have never used gnuplot by itself, so I am unfamiliar with it.

I'm trying to use PGFPlots with gnuplot to graph functions. I have not been able to make anything work at all. I'm reading the PGFPlots manual, but I can't make heads or tails from the instructions.

This is the MWE given in the manual:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot
gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which SHOULD create this:
[image]

**However,** I get nothing except an error:
[image]

I tried modifying TeXworks in the following manner as the PGFPlots manual discussed, trying all the variations I could think of with `pdflatex -shell-enable`, `-shell-enable` `--shell-enable` `-enable-write18`, ad nauseum. Nothing worked.

**Update:** I've additionally tried writing `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`, and placing these before `$fullname`. Still, I am getting the same error.
[image]

I've additionally tried running these commands from the commandline, which does not seem to work either. The most I get is the request to install a package called `dehyph-exptl`, **which is already installed**. I have administrator privileges as well, so that's not the issue. In case you were wondering, `dehyph-exptl` has to do with the special hyphenation of German words apparently? No clue why this package is so important to run gnuplot via TeXworks.
[image]

Lastly, here is evidence that I probably have gnuplot installed and working correctly, however..I know so little about computers that I can't be sure:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody step me through this? I've searched online and in the manuals and haven't found any answers.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial question, are you sure you have `gnuplot` and that it's working?  P.S. it's `gnuplot`, not `GNUPlot` nor `GNU plot`, it has nothing to do with `GNU` project.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the correction. I *think* I have gnuplot and that it's working. http://i.imgur.com/4u3UAUJ.png; http://i.imgur.com/XjlaY3R.png

Comment: I would go a step back and try it on the commandline only. Then follow the advice of running gnuplot manually, as suggested in the error message. This way you can disentangle the various issues that may arise on the way.

Comment: I don't know how to use gnuplot by itself, though if that's what it takes, I'll learn. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "it" in "try it on the commandline only". If by "it", you mean the `pdflatex -shell-escape-` commands, then I have already tried it in every way I can think of. If by "it", you mean trying gnuplot via the commandline, I would be willing to, but since I haven't tried gnuplot's graphical interface yet, I think that might be premature.

Comment: gnuplot should be added to the system path and you should compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex` where `yourfile.tex is the above code.

Comment: You can also check the path requirement by opening command prompt and type `gnuplot --version`. what do you get?

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm not sure where you wanted me to type the above command—in the general commandline or the gnuplot commandline, so I did both. This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/Y3dkElZ.png

Comment: @HarishKumar I apologize, but I am not very good with computers. How do I add gnuplot to the system path? I looked it up online, and this is as far as I got. What do I type into the field after this step?http://i.imgur.com/7hnmHY9.png.

Comment: @HarishKumar When you say "you should compile with pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex", do you mean I should type this into the windows commandline, the gnuplot commandline, write it into the TeXworks Preferences>Typesetting>Processing Tools, or...?

Comment: Your gnuplot is not in the system path. You can either do it by adding your self (you may like this tool: http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/) or you may re-install gnuplot. There will an option to add it to the system path. Read carefully every instruction in every step of installation to find that option. You can use the pdflatex command from texmaker itself.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you so much, Harish. That solved the problem perfectly! I did not even know about system paths or what it meant, so I wouldn't have been able to solve this without your help. (You've helped me in the past as well, so thank you very much.)

Comment: Glad that it worked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The solution from Harish Kumar:**

When installing **gnuplots**, you must check the following box. That is all that is necessary.

[image]

gnuplots is so awesome:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've strugled with the same problem and still got the same error message after making sure gnuplot was installed correctly. My problem was writing the right thing under Tool configuration of pdfLaTeX. I had to write `-enable-write18` *after* `$fullname` and then it worked.